# need help deleting two lines in a text file in python

Tags: python, list, text-files

so i'm working on a school proj and i've been trying to get a function to work for over a week, i still haven't been able to, i need to be able to delete a contact which takes up two lines on the code, the code either erases everything, keeps only the two lines, keeps only one line, or doubles every line except the first one which he erases, please help

```
    contact = input("enter the contact you want to delete")
    with open("repertoire.txt", "r") as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
      with open("repertoire.txt", "w") as g:
        for line in lines:
          if contact in line:
            g.write(line)
            rang = lines.index(line)
            t = lines[rang + 1]
            g.write(t)
```

Comment: `contact = input("enter the contact you want to delete")` ... couple lines later: `if contact in line: g.write(line)`. So what do you expect?

Comment: Apart from that. Don't open an already open file. Don't change the list you are iterating over.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i'm sorry, i probably sound stupid, could you please explain in more details. i don't know what i should be expecting, and for the second comment, how do i change to a write mode without changing the list i'm iterating over

Comment: Start with writing a different file. Reading and writing the same file isn't going to work. Once you get the second file looking great then you can think about changing the names of the file back.

Comment: After you get the invidual files going and you feel comfortable with that, then if you really need to read and write the same file dive into https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#buffered-binary-file-types , I highly doubt you need to but I could be wrong!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
contact = input("enter the contact you want to delete")
with open("repertoire.txt", "r") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
  if contact in line:
     lines[idx] = ""

with open("repertoire.txt", "w") as f:
   for line in lines:
      f.write(line)
```

Comment: hey, thank you so much, sadly it only erases one line while i need both, thank you though, i'll try and make something with it

Comment: If its just the next line you need to delete as well you could do: 
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
  if contact in line:
     lines[idx] = ""
     lines[idx +1] = ""

Comment: thank you! i'll try that

Comment: thank you so much, it works, finally. thank you!